# Find divisors $n_i$ of $a_i$, mutualy coprime, with $\prod n_i=\operatorname{lcm}(a_i)$

Tags: arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, computational-mathematics, least-common-multiple

We are given $k$ positive integers $a_i$, and want as many positive integers $n_i$ each dividing the respective $a_i$, with the $n_i$ mutually coprime, and the product of the $n_i$ equal to to the Least Common Multiple of the $a_i$.
<sub>Note: $1$ is coprime with every positive integer, so $n_i=1$ is sometime fine.</sub>

There's a simple method when we can put the $a_i$ as $\prod p_j^{m_{j,i}}$ for primes $p_j$. We initially set all the $n_i$ to $a_i$; then for each prime $p_j$ appearing in the factorizations of the $a_i$, we choose one of possibly several $i$ with maximal multiplicity $m_{j,i}$, and for each *other* $i$ divide $n_i$ by $p_j^{m_{j,i}}$.

**Can we proceed with no factorization** whatsoever, or if impossible with as little factorization work as possible (perhaps using a Greatest Common Divisor primitive and/or other computationally efficient methods)?

---

Given $a_0=554400=2^5\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^2\cdot 7\cdot 11$, $a_1=4422600=2^3\cdot 3^5\cdot 5^2\cdot 7\cdot 13$
$k=2$, the only 4 solutions are:

- $n_0=2^5\cdot 5^2\cdot 7\cdot 11=61600$, $n_1=3^5\cdot 13=3159$
- $n_0=2^5\cdot 5^2\cdot 11=8800$, $n_1=3^5\cdot 7\cdot 13=22113$
- $n_0=2^5\cdot 7\cdot 11=2464$, $n_1=3^5\cdot 5^2\cdot 13=78975$
- $n_0=2^5\cdot 11=352$, $n_1=3^5\cdot 5^2\cdot 7\cdot 13=552825$

---

Solving the problem for $k=2$ leads to a solution for larger $k$, by iteratively replacing $a_i$ and $a_{i'}$ with the $n_i$ and $n_{i'}$ obtained for the $k(k-1)/2$ pairs of $i,i'$ with $i<i'$. However that seems less than optimal.

---

The problem is of general interest in large CRT problems. The initial motivating context was applying the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) in the final step of the [Pohlig-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm) algorithm with composite moduli, [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/67093/555).

Comment: Are the $a_i$ required to be distinct? Otherwise taking $a_1 = a_2 = pq$ a semiprime would give you an efficient way to factorize semiprimes, so I doubt an efficient method exists. Edit: and *just* distinctness wouldn't help you of course, because you could double one of the $a_i$ in my example.

Comment: @Mees de Vries: If all the $a_i$ are equal (including of unknown hard factorization), we can set one $n_i$ to that, and all the other $n_i$ to $1$. For $k=2$, $a_1=r\, a_0$ with arbitrary unknown $r$, we can efficiently detect this as $a_1\bmod a_0=0$, set $n_0=1$, and $n_1=a_1$. Thus neither of these examples show that a general solution of the problem would solve factorization.

Comment: Oops. My bad. Nice question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no known polynomial time algorithm for finding prime factorizations of integers, so here is an algorithm which, while far from perfect, still runs in polynomial time.

Let $A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_k\}$, let $M$ be the maximum element of $A$, and let $n=\log_2{M}$. We will determine the computational complexity in terms of $n$ and $k$.

Every prime $p$ has a largest power $m_p$ amongst elements of $A$, which is to say $m_p$ is the power of $p$ in $\text{lcm}\hspace{1pt}A$. Our first goal will be to find values $b_i$, which will be a multiple of only those primes $p$ for which the power of $p$ in $a_i$ is $m_p$. We will then use these to find values $c_i$, which will be the product of values $p^{m_p}$ such that $p^{m_p}$ divides $a_i$. Finally, we will consider these against each other to determine $n_i$. This will be completed in $\mathcal{O}(k\cdot n^5+k^2\cdot n)$ time, which is indeed a polynomial.

For each $a_i$, we define

$$b_i=\frac{a_i^{n+1}}{\gcd(a_i^{n+1},\text{lcm}\hspace{1pt}\{a_j^n\text{ s.t. }j\neq i\}\})}$$

Let us figure out what is happening here. What the denominator does is find the the maximum power of every prime which divides an element of $A\backslash\{a_i\}$, and multiplies that maximum by $n$. It then takes these powers and compares them with those found in $a_i^{n+1}$, and takes the smaller one. If the power of $p$ found in $a_i$ is $p^{m_p}$, where $m_p$ must be at most $n$, then $p^{m_p}\cdot(n+1)>p^{m_p}\cdot n$, so $p$ will divide $b_i$, and otherwise, since $(p^{m_p}-1)\cdot(n+1)<p^{m_p}\cdot n$, $p$ will not divide $b_i$. Thus $p$ divides $b_i$ if and only if $p^{m_p}$ divides $a_i$. This process will take $\mathcal{O}(k\cdot n^4)$ time, resulting from taking $k$ $\gcd$ functions on values with at most about $n^2$ bits.

Now we wish to find $c_i$, for which the power of $p$ is $m_p$ if $p^{m_p}$ divides $a_i$ and 0 otherwise. To do this, we will do the following (note the subscripts have been removed here for clarity):

```
x = gcd(a,b)
while (x != 1)
    c *= x
    a /= x
    x = gcd(a,b)
```

Every iteration, this will multiply the power of $p$ in $c_i$ by at least 1 so long as it is not yet $p^{m_p}$. Thus it will take at most $m_p\leq n$ iterations, each taking $\mathcal{O}(n^5)$ time due to the multiplication, so the process of finding values of $c_i$ takes at most $\mathcal{O}(k\cdot n^5)$ time.

Finally, we need to find our values of $n_i$. We find these in order. We simply let $n_1=c_1$, then take the $\gcd$ of this with the other values of $c_i$ and divide these old values of $c_i$ by that $\gcd$ to get new values. We then do this with every other value from 2 to $k$, taking $\mathcal{O}(k^2\cdot n+n^2)$ time, giving us working values of $n_i$ in polynomial time.

Comment: This will take some time to digest, but seems to be what I hoped. Any reference?

Comment: I did look up the time complexities of multiplication, exponentiation and gcd, which are $n^2$, $n^2\cdot m$ where $m$ is the exponent and $n$, respectively (even thought you can do better it’s a bit easier on the eyes to use integer powers). Additionally, it’s useful to know what Big-O notation is, which is explained pretty well on the wikipedia page of that name. Other than that, unfortunately I can’t link you to anything externally, but if you have questions or advice on better writing (this is my second solution here) let me know!

Comment: To clarify: It will take _me_ some time to understand this answer, and mark it as accepted. So far everything adds up and I see no gap. I'm familiar with big-O notation. Thanks!